# UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm learning Elasticsearch and I want to search data using hibernate search but this error happened:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsInt(JsonElement.java:243)
    at io.searchbox.core.SearchResult.getTotal(SearchResult.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.impl.ElasticsearchHSQueryImpl.execute(ElasticsearchHSQueryImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.impl.ElasticsearchHSQueryImpl.queryEntityInfos(ElasticsearchHSQueryImpl.java:275)
```

Here is my dependency

```
at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:197)
        at org.hibernate.search.jpa.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.getResultList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.demos.hswithes.model.Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-search-elasticsearch</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>
```

I use Java 8 and Elasticsearch 6.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate Search 5.6 is very old. It [only supports Elasticsearch 2.0 - 2.4](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.6/).

The only version of Hibernate Search that is tested with Elasticsearch 6.8 is [Hibernate Search 6.0](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/). If you just started working on your application, I highly recommend using that version. It exposes a different API, but it's much more adapted to Elasticsearch.

Make sure to use Hibernate ORM 5.4, too. Hibernate ORM 5.1.3 will not work with Hibernate Search 6.0.